# Period of a constant function.

Tags: functions

Function f is said to be periodic if, for some nonzero constant P, we have

$f
(
x
+
P
)
=
f
(
x
)$

${\displaystyle f(x+P)=f(x)}$
for all values of x in the domain. A nonzero constant P for which this is the case is called a period of the function.

Can we say period of a constant function is
$$Lim_{x\to0^+}x$$ because it satisfy positive condition as well as least. Or I didn’t understood definition of period?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking. Perhaps you're missing an equals sign somewhere?

Comment: I am saying weather that limit is period of constant function or not.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, any constant function can be described as being periodic. But since there isn't a minimum value of $P$ for which $f(x+P) = f(x)$, we say that $f(x)$ is periodic with no period.

On the other hand, $\sin x$, for example, is a common periodic function with a minimum value for $P$, which is $2\pi$, so we say this function has a period of $2\pi$

Comment: I am asking weather that limit is period of constant function. That limit is least positive so it should be period for constantly function.

Comment: I would argue that limit is not the period, only because that limit simplifies to $0$ and $P$ must be a positive real number. If you accept them, a possible argument could be made using [infinitesimals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal) but they generally aren't used too much in practice.